# How to check if a text has request for information

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, opennlp

I have been trying to see if there are ways to classify the text if it is requesting for information. I feel like NLP is the way, is there a better approach?

For example:

1. Hi, Can you share your school name? <<-- Yes
2. What is your school name? <<-- Yes
3. My address is XYZ. <<-- No
4. What is your PIN? <<-- Yes

Thanks,
Vinod.

Answer (score 0):

This can be framed as a text classification task. If you have a sufficient amount of training examples, you can train a binary classifier to predict whether a sentence is asking for any information.

If you do not have a dataset, you may consider forming a dataset using natural language sentences and natural language questions. I assume a sentence that asks for information is basically a question. So, in essence, you want to identify if a sentence is a question or not.

You may also consider predicting a sentence as a question based on patterns. For example, sentences start with an interrogative word are questions. You can have additional rules to identify a question pattern.